# How to set version of wfs-t in openlayers-3?

Tags: openlayers, wfs-t

I'm using `wfs-t` in [OpenLayers-3.6](http://openlayers.org) according to [here](http://wordpress-dbauszus.rhcloud.com/?p=71). I modified a feature and then sent a wfs request as follows:

```
var properties = modifiedFeature.getProperties();
delete properties.boundedBy;
newFeature = new ol.Feature(properties);
newFeature.setId(features[i].getId());

var node = wfs.writeTransaction(null, [newFeature], null, {
    featureType: "Calk:Point", //geoserver Layer Name
    featureNS: "http://itsme.calk.ir", // Edit Workspace Namespace URI
    srsName: "EPSG:4326"
});
var s = new XMLSerializer();

var url = "http://localhost:8084/geoserver/wfs";

Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'proxy.cgi?url=' + encodeURIComponent(url),
    method: 'POST',
    xmlData: s.serializeToString(node),
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'text/xml'
    },
    success: function(response_) {
        response = response_;
    }
});
```

The default version that `OpenLayers` works is "1.1.0", In this setting, I want to work with version "2.0.0". ***How can I set the version***?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no difference in the format of WFS 1.1.0, and 2.0.0. Both of them uses GML3. You cannot set the version, but you can change the GML version in `ol.format.WFS` to write in GML2, which corresponds to WFS 1.0.0. You can read more about the differences [here](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wfs/basics.html).

Comment: @Gabor Farkes, WFS 1.1.0 is using GML 3.1.1 and WFS 2.0 GML 3.2. There may not be difference in the parameters which are used in  WFS-T requests but VERSION=2.0.0 is anyhow compulsory. I would have a look at the OpenLayers.Format.WFST.v2_0_0 constructor http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Format/WFST/v2_0_0-js.html.

Comment: @user30184 Nice proposal. As you can see in the answer below, WFS-T in OL3 is hard coded to version 1.1.0. There is no other choice, than to write a custom WFS-T parser for v2.0.0. For this, the OL2 [source code](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/master/lib/OpenLayers/Format/WFST/v2_0_0.js) is indeed a very good starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source code, the `ol.format.WFS` constructor can be customized to support different WFS formats (with `gmlFormat`, and `schemaLocation`), but it only affects the reading process, not its `writeTransaction` method. As you can see in the code below, the method is hard coded to support only WFS 1.1.0 transactions. There is a [mail](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ol3-dev/fD34lChfvvc) on the ol3 dev mailing list about not planning WFS 2.0 support, but it's quite old.

```
/**
 * Encode format as WFS `Transaction` and return the Node.
 *
 * @param {Array.<ol.Feature>} inserts The features to insert.
 * @param {Array.<ol.Feature>} updates The features to update.
 * @param {Array.<ol.Feature>} deletes The features to delete.
 * @param {olx.format.WFSWriteTransactionOptions} options Write options.
 * @return {Node} Result.
 * @api stable
 */
ol.format.WFS.prototype.writeTransaction = function(inserts, updates, deletes,
    options) {
  var objectStack = [];
  var node = ol.xml.createElementNS('http://www.opengis.net/wfs',
      'Transaction');
  node.setAttribute('service', 'WFS');
  node.setAttribute('version', '1.1.0');
  var baseObj, obj;
  if (goog.isDef(options)) {
    baseObj = goog.isDef(options.gmlOptions) ? options.gmlOptions : {};
    if (goog.isDef(options.handle)) {
      node.setAttribute('handle', options.handle);
    }
  }
  ol.xml.setAttributeNS(node, 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance',
      'xsi:schemaLocation', this.schemaLocation_);
  if (goog.isDefAndNotNull(inserts)) {
    obj = {node: node, featureNS: options.featureNS,
      featureType: options.featureType, featurePrefix: options.featurePrefix};
    goog.object.extend(obj, baseObj);
    ol.xml.pushSerializeAndPop(obj,
        ol.format.WFS.TRANSACTION_SERIALIZERS_,
        ol.xml.makeSimpleNodeFactory('Insert'), inserts,
        objectStack);
  }
  if (goog.isDefAndNotNull(updates)) {
    obj = {node: node, featureNS: options.featureNS,
      featureType: options.featureType, featurePrefix: options.featurePrefix};
    goog.object.extend(obj, baseObj);
    ol.xml.pushSerializeAndPop(obj,
        ol.format.WFS.TRANSACTION_SERIALIZERS_,
        ol.xml.makeSimpleNodeFactory('Update'), updates,
        objectStack);
  }
  if (goog.isDefAndNotNull(deletes)) {
    ol.xml.pushSerializeAndPop({node: node, featureNS: options.featureNS,
      featureType: options.featureType, featurePrefix: options.featurePrefix},
    ol.format.WFS.TRANSACTION_SERIALIZERS_,
    ol.xml.makeSimpleNodeFactory('Delete'), deletes,
    objectStack);
  }
  if (goog.isDef(options.nativeElements)) {
    ol.xml.pushSerializeAndPop({node: node, featureNS: options.featureNS,
      featureType: options.featureType, featurePrefix: options.featurePrefix},
    ol.format.WFS.TRANSACTION_SERIALIZERS_,
    ol.xml.makeSimpleNodeFactory('Native'), options.nativeElements,
    objectStack);
  }
  return node;
};
```